# Adding conditional formatting to the status line in GNU screen

Tags: gnu-screen, conditional-formatting

In GNU screen in the status it is possible to put conditional things, such as

```
%?%F%{+b r}%:%{+b b}%?
```

%F is the test; if true it turns on bold red formatting %{+b r}, whereas if false it turns on bold blue formatting %{+b b}.

Conditional statements like this with %F (which tests for focus) are the only ones I have seen in examples of .screenrc files or in the screen manual.

What other conditional statements can be used? The manual says:
"the  part  to the next '%?' is displayed only if a '%' escape inside the part expands to a non-empty string"
which is a little confusing. Can I for example change the colour depending on the time of day or day of the week?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a script that outputs something when the condition is true. This example will output a space when the time is between 9 AM and 4:59 PM.

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%H)
if (( time >= 9 && time <= 16 ))
then
    echo " "
fi
```

Save this script. Let's name it "screenbtdaytime". Also, do `chmod u+x screenbtdaytime` (or `+x` without the `u` to make it universally executable).

To demo this, use this line instead of the `if` above so the change occurs every 10 seconds so you don't have to wait all day to see the effect:

```
if (( $(date +%s) / 10 % 2 ))    # temporary for demo
```

Now in `screen` press Ctrl-a and **:** to bring up the command prompt and type in these two commands:

```
backtick 1 0 1 /path/to/screenbttime
caption always "%?%{+b by}%1`%:%{+b yb} %?%C | %D, %M %d, %Y"
```

You can use `hardstatus` instead of `caption` if you prefer, I believe.

Changing the `0` to `60` in the `backtick` command will make the updates happen once a minute rather than at the default rate.

This assigns the script to backtick command 1 (the first "1") which is used in the caption where you see `` %1` ``. You can have other commands associated with other numbers so you can have multiple things going on.

Since the script outputs a space during the designated time, it triggers the conditional `%?` which is set to output color codes for blue text on a yellow background. The "else" portion (`%:`) is performed when there's no output from the script and the colors are yellow on a blue background. An extra space is added in the "else" to visually match the one that is displayed as the output of the script.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot. It does indeed work in the hardstatus line as well.